# Customize Antd AutoComplete to use {children} for both dataSource and input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Can I customize both 1) dataSource and 2) input when using `{children}` approach?

Docs say:

> **children (for customize input element)**
>   customize input element
>   HTMLInputElement / HTMLTextAreaElement / React.ReactElement
>
> **children (for dataSource)**
>   Data source for autocomplete
>   React.ReactElement / Array

I got it working using one or the other but not both. Really annoying that is no `renderOption` attribute or something similar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use both, you can write something like this:

```
const results = dataSource.map(x => (
  <Select.Option key={x} {/* props you want */}>{x}</Option>
))

<AutoComplete dataSource={results}>
  <Search placeholder="Search..." />
</AutoComplete>
```

Comment: The dataSource prop is now deprecated (ant 4.2), and replaced by options prop. But the options props doesn´t work with an array of <Select.Option>. Any advice?

Comment: @ThomasStjernegaardJeppesen I'm not familiar with v4, but I think you can just replace array of `<Select.Option>` with array object: `[{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3}]`, I didn't test it, can you try it works?